# ViewModel not displaying

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, button, view

Im learning how to use WPF on C# and ive hit a stumbling block, im trying to open a new window/view when i click a button
This is the first window code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace PROG6221_POE_Tarisai_Gonah_18028480
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void OpenWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window f1 = new Window();
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            f1.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the second window:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace PROG6221_POE_Tarisai_Gonah_18028480.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OpenWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow objmain = new MainWindow();
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            objmain.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

I've set it up so when the respective button is clicked it allows me to go on the first window and second window. When I run the code it shows the first view and then when I click the button to go to the second one I get a BLANK WHITE SCREEN

does anyone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with  Window1 f1 = new Window1();  at MainWindow  ... because you are creating only new window, but not the proper one !  Use the same namespace PROG6221_POE_Tarisai_Gonah_18028480 !

Comment: It gives me an error it says namespace not found

Comment: Use the same namespace for both windows  PROG6221_POE_Tarisai_Gonah_18028480 !